# How add the elements of json to List in android?

Tags: android

I am new to Android application development.

In my application i have one Json file like ["India","USA"]

My requirement is add the elements of that Json file to ArrayList.

please help me to go forward.

thank you,
bye....

Comment: [what you have tried](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_nf=3&tok=kDsmdPKdUwnC6cpXx-SYkw&cp=6&gs_id=m&xhr=t&q=json+parsing+in+android&pf=p&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=json+p&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=5aadb5e1b45e4dbb&bpcl=38897761&biw=1366&bih=680)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Reader reader = new StringReader(json);

JsonReader jsr = new JsonReader(reader);

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

JsonElement rawJson = parser.parse(jsr);

JsonArray asJsonArray = rawJson.getAsJsonArray();

for (JsonElement jsonElement : asJsonArray) {
   jsonElement.getAsString();
}
```

or

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>(){}.getType();

Collection<Integer> ints2 = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
```

Use GSON library in both the instances.